# How to check if notification delays are because of WiFi?

Tags: wi-fi, notifications, whatsapp-messenger, instagram

I sometimes get delayed or no notification of whatsapp and Instagram. How to check if it's my wifi's issue or if it's my phone's?

Comment: That depends on the delay. If it is less than about 15 minutes then this is normal behavior. Android does not keep the connection to the Google push server permanently open to save battery. Instead it tries to aggregate requests to make network requests more efficient.

Comment: Is there any way to check if it's due to google push server or if it's my phone's issue.

Comment: The Google push server is never the problem because your phone always connects to the push server and asks for outstanding messages (polling) not the other way around. On your device the Google Play Services are responsible for doing so.